# Bootstrap Drop Down Nav not working Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-modal

My drop down menu is not working within my rails 6 app.  Please see the following files:

_navigation.erb.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
    </div>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <div class="nav pull-right">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        Menu
      </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

        <li><%= link_to "Add New Festival", new_festival_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Add New Review", new_review_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "View Festivals", festivals_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "View Reviews", reviews_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "View Cities", cities_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method:'delete' %></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my application.js file:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.


import "bootstrap"
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

Here is my environment.js file:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')


const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
    'Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Please let me know if any other file would be valuable in helping to solve this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your jQuery working at all?

Comment: Try putting bootstrap last in the application.js. Also, why is it `import "bootstrap"`? Why not `require("bootstrap")`?

Answer (score 0):

If @hashrocket is in the right lead and you've got no jQuery working, it may be due to you needing the following in your *environment.js* before the *exports*:

```
environment.loaders.append('expose', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: '$'
  }, {
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: 'jQuery',
  }]
})
```

You also need to *npm install* **expose-loader**, in case you haven't.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried this, but my jquery is still not working.  Do you have any other ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is because you are using jquery 3.5.0+. I have myself experienced issues with 3.5.0+, but when I downgrade jquery to 3.4.1 it works:

```
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
```

Here's the environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")
environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: 'jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery',
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
module.exports = environment
```

application.js:

```
import "bootstrap"
```

All the jquery releases that you can install with yarn command:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: I tried this, but my jquery does not seem to be working.  Do you have any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this:

`<div class="nav-collapse collapse">`

Now, it is working.

Comment: I just got the same issue. The solution was to replace import by require in my app/javascript/packs/application.js. 
require('bootstrap')

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @popperjs/core
```

my problem solved this code. I added other comments suggest solutions but my working still same problem. But with trying this nmp popperjs install code thats now working dropdown menu. Maybe this code working update npm package.